# Can I use normal (rails default) JSON response on Ember Data?

Tags: json, api, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a project using `Ember`/`Ember-Data` and there is a related/already existing service which is provide API with JSON response.

My project must interact with that service, but the response from that API is someting like below:

```
{ "id": 39402, "name": "My Name" }
```

or

```
[ {"id": 38492, "name": "Other Name" } ]
```

there is no `person:` or `persons:` that is required by `Ember-Data` compatable response.

How can I using this response on `Ember-Data` without change on the service or without build API gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ember-Data` uses `DS.RestAdapter`, which in turn uses `DS.RESTSerializer` which extends from `DS.JSONSerializer` for serializing, extracting and massaging data that comes in from the server.

Since in your case you already have the data in your payload, all you need to do for **reading** the data is override `extract` method in the `JSONSerializer` which is actually quite simple.

If you are using `ember-cli` (which you should :)), your `person.js` file located inside your `app/serializers` directory would look as follows.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  extract: function(store, primaryType, payload) {
    return payload;
  }
});
```

If you are not using `ember-cli`, you can do the following:

```
App.PersonSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  extract: function(store, primaryType, payload) {
    return payload;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested with custom Serializer extended from ActiveModelSerializer and overriding normalizePayload method, but it is not good for my case. I have multuple models and I need single super custom serializer to be extended. I will try your advise. btw, is there any restriction when using JSONSrializer with ActiveModelAdapter? or the method can be used on ActiveModelSerializer? Finally, what is the full flow of extract, normalize, and so on? Is there any referense for understand the sequence? Thanks again.

Comment: Check out this repo I quickly threw together... https://github.com/kalmanh/ember-data-with-default-rails-json

Comment: Ok, I will check yours. thanks very much. Anyway, I tested overriding `extract` and works fine, and I find out if `extract` was overrided so, `normalizePayload` is not called, and I tested again with "just log and call super()" override both, `normalizePayload` is called inside of `extract` method. I need more study on the steps. thanks.

Comment: And I'm happy with `extract` because I do not worrry about model name or plural (which is important on `normalizePayload`, so I can make single Serializer and use is for more models by extends.

Comment: Oops! I found some issue while override `extract` fully. issue is described in other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215984/ember-js-how-do-i-load-related-models-while-loading-main-model-from-server-that/29223830#29223830) so... do not override `extract` without understanding of super method or side effect of it.